# LibC++_shared is Present in APK but Not Found When Loading Libraries During Execution?

Tags: android, opencv, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, libs

I'm working on an Android project with a pre-compiled `.so` file for OpenCV. The original distribution I used as my base (courtesy of [QuickBird Studios](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.quickbirdstudios/opencv-contrib/4.5.3.0)) contains 2 `.so` files: `libopencv_java4` and `libc++_shared`. The two `.so` files are taken from a `.aar` library which I had to unpack in order to address a known, long-standing issue in the OpenCV Android implementation. These two SOs are stored in the same folder in my project tree, as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hq727.png). The other ABIs share identical structure to `arm64-v8a`.

When compiling the APK with Intellij IDEA (v2022.1.3), the APK analyzer shows that both `.so` files have been packaged in to `lib/{ABI}`, as can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBucT.png) (in this case, the ABI is `arm64-v8a`). So far, so good.

However, when I go to load the OpenCV library (which calls upon `libc++_shared`), I receive the following error:

```
W/System.err: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libc++_shared.so" not found: needed by {omitted}/base.apk/lib/arm64-v8a/libopencv_java4.so in namespace classloader-namespace
```

I've attempted building the APK without including `libstdc++_shared`, under the pretense that Gradle claims to be able to include the C++ shared libraries automatically. This failed with the same error message as above, with no `libc++_shared.so` in the APK.

I've also attempted to create a dummy native C++ file, in order to get `libc++_shared` added via CMake during the Gradle build process. This also failed with the above error. I did not think to check the APK during this attempt.

In a previous iteration of this project (before I discovered the bug in the OpenCV Android implementation), I was able to compile and run without issue by including the `.aar` file as an external library.

Between each of the above attempts, I've performed a full Gradle cache invalidation to make sure I'm not keeping broken files from previous tries.

I'm completely flummoxed. Did I break something when I unpacked the `.aar` to fix the bug? How can I get Android to acknowledge what's inside the APK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue after upgrading the Gradle plugin. the nonsense disappear after I also upgrade the Gradle build tool.

```
dependencies {
    //after upgrad from 3.5.1 the link error disappear
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4"
    ...
}
```

Comment: Accepting this answer in case anyone else comes across this question, although my solution ended up being to just refactor my entire project to pull my JNI Libraries from Maven Repositories directly rather than from local.

Comment: Another case that could cause c++ not to be found during load time is that you manually replace your AAR file without cleaning the project. in this case, go to Build->Clean project and rebuild again.